# How do I properly organize my terraform configuration?

Tags: devops, terraform

I'm trying to implement a couple of services using terraform and I am not quite sure how to efficiently handle variables (ideally the proper terraform way).

Let's say I want to spin up a couple of vms in a couple of datacenters, one each and every datacenter differs slightly (think aws-regions, VPC-IDs, Securitygroup-IDs etc.)

Currently (in ansible) I have a dict that contains a dict per region containing the configuration specific to the region.

I would like to be able to deploy each datacenter on its own.

I have read through a lot of documentation and I came up with a couple of ways I could use to realise this.

### 1. use vars-files

have one vars-file per datacenter containing exactly the config per DC and call terraform -var-file ${file}

That somehow seems not that cool, but I'd rethink that if there was a way to dynamically load the vars-file according to the datacenter-name I set.

### 2. use maps

have loads of maps in an auto-loaded vars-file and reference them by data-center-name.

I've looked at this and that does not look like it's really readable in the future. It could work out if I create separate workspaces per datacenter, but since maps are string -> string only I can't use lists.

### 3. use an external source

Somehow that sounds good, but since the docs already label the external data source as an 'escape hatch for exceptional situations' it's probably not what I'm looking for.

### 4. use modules and vars in .tf-file

Set up a module that does the work, set up one directory per datacenter, set up one .tf-file per datacenter-directory that contains the appropriate variables and uses the module

Seems the most elegant, but then I don't have one central config but lots of them to keep track of.

Which way is the 'proper' way to tackle this?

Comment: This might be easier to answer if you posted minimal code examples for each of your options.

Answer (score 0):

To at least provide an answer to anyone else that's got the same problem:

I went ahead with option 4.

That means I've set up modules that take care of orchestrating the services, defaulting all variables I use to reflect the testing-environment (as in: If you don't specify anything extra you're setting up testing, if you want anything else you've got to override the defaults).

Then I set up three 'branches' in my directory tree, `testing`, `staging` and `production`, and added subdirectories for every datacenter/region.

Every region-directory contains `main.tf` that sources the modules, all but testing contain `terraform.tfvars` that define the overrides. I also have `backend.tf` in all of those directories that defines the backends for state-storage and locking.

I initially thought that doing it this way is a bit too complex and that I may be overengineering the problem, but it turned out that this solution is easier to understand and maintain.